# How to automatically adjust height of box depending on screen size?

Tags: css

Right now, I have this code:

```
.form1 {
text-align: justify;
height: 250px;
padding: 15px;
border-radius: 20px;
margin: 20px 15% auto 15%;
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);}
```

So the height of the form is set to 250px for a medium sized screen (works when it covers the full screen of my laptop). However, when I reduce the size of the window (and because I am using columns), the text covers more space so the height would have to increase. How do I make it adjust automatically depending on the screen size?

Comment: Are you using any frameworks like Bootstrap etc...?

Answer (score 0):

Using `min-height: 250px;` should bring the results which you expect.